# code works on emulator but not physical device

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have code that I'm trying to submit to a database, and the code works fine on an emulator but as soon as I move to an actual device the same code will no longer work. I think it has to do with the time() function in my php (I don't know what else it could be) but am I missing something obvious? this code on a physcial android device always throws "Oops! An error occurred." but on my emulator on my computer it works just fine. I've checked to make sure that I uploaded fresh copies of the project.

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['assemblyLotNumber']) && isset($_POST['assemblyID']) && isset($_POST['assemblerID']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {

    $assemblyLotNumber = $_POST['assemblyLotNumber'];
    $assemblyID = $_POST['assemblyID'];
    $assemblerID = $_POST['assemblerID'];   
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    $time = time();
    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO assemblylot (assemblyLotNumber, assemblyID, assemblerID, date, isPremade, quantity) VALUES('$assemblyLotNumber', '$assemblyID', '$assemblerID', $time, 1, '$quantity')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "premade assembly successfully created.";
        $response["date"] = $time;
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
        $response["date"] = $time;
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

this is where I call it in the code

```
public void submitAssemblyLot(Assembly a) {
        List<NameValuePair> assemblyParam = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        assemblyParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("assemblyLotNumber", Integer.toString(a.getAssemblyLotNumber())));
        assemblyParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("assemblyID", Integer.toString(a.getAssemblyID())));
        assemblyParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("assemblerID", Integer.toString(a.getAssemblerID())));     
        try {
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_submit_assembly_lot, "POST", assemblyParam);
            String message = json.getString("message");
            String date1 = json.getString("time");
            Log.d("submitAssemblyLot", message);
            Log.d("submitAssemblyLot", date1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Find out which error, with a stack trace. i.e debug. There's definitely no need to play the guessing game at least.

Comment: Stupid question but did you set the right adress to connect to your database?

Comment: Yes I can connect with other scripts just fine Quentin, and Keyser, I'm not getting a JSONException so there is nothing to catch? My code just fails to inset the row .

Comment: Why not `$response['message'] = mysql_error();`?  While you're at it, why are you using ext/mysql at all?  And, have you never heard of SQL injection?

Comment: Agreed with eggyal when it comes to using `mysql_error()` to find more meaningful result and better idea of why it's failing.